# Joining part of composite key in JPA having join table

Tags: java, jpa, join, spring-boot, composite-key

I have a join condition between 2 of my classes which are joined using a join table.

Item Class:

```
public class Item {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "item_workflow", joinColumns = 
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_id",
referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Workflow> workflow;}
```

Workflow Class:

```
public class Workflow {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String actor;
private String assignee;
private String date;
private String team;}
```

These 2 tables are joined by a join table which has the following columns:

```
|Item_id | Workflow_id|
```

The above code is working fine. I am now trying to add a composite key to workflow class which would be a combination of id, actor and date. I want to do this as there should be no workflow id with same actor on the same time stamp (date) twice.

When I used the id class to create the composite key, i got the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(id) of application.model.Item.workflow referencing application.model.Workflow not mapped to a single property
```

Following is the Id class:

```
public class Workflow_comp_key implements Serializable {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String actor;
private String date;}
```

After adding the id class to workflow, this is how it looks:

```
@IdClass(Workflow_comp_key.class)
public class Workflow {
public static final String FIND_ALL = "findAll";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Id
private String actor;
private String assignee;
@Id
private String date;
private String team;
}
```

I searched for this issue and most of the answers asked me to add all components of composite key in join condition. I tried the following:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "item_workflow", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                                  @JoinColumn(name = "actor", referencedColumnName = "actor"),
                                  @JoinColumn(name = "date", referencedColumnName = "date")})
    private List<Workflow> workflow;
```

Once i add this, the compiler is not able to find actor and date in the join table which is obvious, they do not exist in the join table. following is the issue:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [actor] in table [item_workflow]
```

Now i am clueless as to what should I do to have this accomplished. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: there is no need for the class `Workflow_comp_key` as long as you have to latest versions. simply add `@Id` to every attribute you want in your `Workflow` class as this creates a composite id with the 3 attributes

Comment: I still get the same error without the `Workflow_comp_key` : `referencedColumnNames(id) of application.model.Item.workflow referencing application.model.Workflow not mapped to a single property`

Comment: do i see it right that you want a unidirectional `OneToMany` relationship? if yes, would it be possible to delete the join table and move the item id into the workflow table? if that is also possible, you can try a `@ElementCollection` like this: `@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @CollectionTable(name = "Workflow", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Item_Id"))`